# If it's the amps that kills, why is it possible to survive a shock from a 12.4 amps?

Tags: amperage

"It's the amps that kills" you is well know and well documented. There are even charts showing the physiological effects of various currents.

[image]

According to several thread, there are people putting their tongue on the end of chargor (like phone/laptop power connector) and reporting they only get a mild shock.

On this [thread](http://ask.metafilter.com/60398/Will-a-laptop-power-connector-kill-you-if-you-put-the-end-in-your-mouth), the experiment was done with a 85 watt adapter putting out about 12.4 amps at 6.86 volts put on the tongue (so a wet part of the body where the resistance should not be  20 to 100kOhm but about 1kOhm).

Based on the chart a current of 12.4amp is well over the death limit.

So how is it possible that a current of 12.4amp doesn't kill someone?

Source for the chart: https://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~p616/safety/fatal_current.html

Comment: Apply ohms law to the figures you quote and you'll see they can't all be true. Also, actually dissipating 85w on your tongue would leave a substantial burn.

Comment: Besides the numbers from the 'experiment' being nonsense, the hazard of a shock depends a lot on where the current flows in the body.  I'm sure you could put huge currents along one leg, say, with bad burning but no (immediate) fatality.  The big risk is where current flows through the chest, which is why one-hand-to-the-other types of shocks tend to be considered very dangerous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you heard of ohms law?

I = V/R

Hence I = 6.86 volts / 1kohm = 6.8 mA.

The power supply is capable of outputting 12 amps but if the load is 1kohm it isn't taking 12 amps. People have been licking batteries for years: -

[image]

[image]

[Here's](http://earthsky.org/earth/what-type-of-electricity-hurts-more-ac-or-dc) a website that takes you through the testing done in the picture immediately above.

Answer (score 5):

You have a 2L bottle of water.

You are thirsty.

Do you drink the entire 2L in one go ? It depends on how thirsty you are. You can drink the entire 2L bottle at once, if you are really thirsty. But chances are, you would only have a glass, maybe two. It depends on how thirsty you are.

Similarly, just because a power supply can supply 1A, or 10A, or 100A, that doesn't mean a circuit will take all of it. It will draw as much as it needs. If your circuit requires alot of power for it to operate, it will only draw that much. Voltage and resistance, play a part in how much current is drawn.

I = V/R (Ohm's Law).

As the math in Andy Akas answer shows, the actual current being drawn onto the tongue was only ~7mA.